# Identical Zero Sets for two distinct irreducible polynomials

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

In [these notes on page 13](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~r-ash/Algebra/Chapter8.pdf#page=13), question number 9 asks to give example of two irreducible polynomials in $\mathbb{R}[X,Y]$ with identical zero sets. I can think of trivial examples like $x^2+y^2$ and $x^4+y^2$, both of which vanish only on the origin. Are there non-trivial examples where the zero sets are dimension $1$, for example?

Comment: I think the second example is not irreducible.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is no. This is simply [Bezout's Theorem.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout's_theorem) A proof may be found in Michael Artin's Algebra.